# `rtorrent` with many torrents eventually gets timeouts on all of them

Tags: linux, networking

I'm running `rtorrent 0.9.6/0.13.6` with the following `.rtorrent.rc` with ~500 torrents:

```
directory = /var/lib/stuff

schedule = watch_directory,5,5,load_start=/var/lib/torrents/*.torrent
schedule = low_diskspace,5,60,close_low_diskspace=10G

encryption = allow_incoming,enable_retry,try_outgoing
dht = disable

network.http.max_open.set = 99
network.max_open_files.set = 600
network.max_open_sockets.set = 999

pieces.hash.on_completion.set = no
check_hash = no
port_range = 1027-1027
```

`/etc/sysctl.conf` is as follows:

```
fs.file-max=500000
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=1024 65535
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 12582912 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 12582912 16777216
```

These values are, in fact, loaded via `sysctl -p`

[Plex](https://www.plex.tv/) and a few more `rtorrent` instances (much smaller ones) run on the same server, so my first inkling was that I was running out of outbound ports, hence the amendments to the configs above.

The tracker(s) in question are not experiencing issues at the moment.

The issuous scenario is:

1. Start this `rtorrent` instance,
2. All torrents hash over time and successfully connect to the tracker(s) and peers. I can see these up on the tracker(s),
3. Over the course of ~24hrs, some and then all of the torrents show errors: `Timeout was reached`, some with `SSL connect error`. `rtorrent` itself becomes extremely laggy and almost unresponsive,
4. I kill `rtorrent` with `Ctrl-QQ` and start it over again.

What can possibly be the issue here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As unfortunate it is, this issue was eventually solved by updating system packages. Similar issues were reported with certain versions of `libcurl` (my version was older).